# How to refresh values into onLocationChanged

Tags: android, google-maps, on-location-changed

I have a map and I want the values, that I printed at markers, change during location such as latitude and longitude.Below it's the `onLocationChanged`

```
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                    mGoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(Tab2Map.this.getActivity()));
                    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                    String snippet = "SignalStrength:"+current+
                            '\n'+"Rsrp: " +MapRsrp+'\n'+"Rsrq: "+MapRsrq+'\n'+"Rssnr: "+MapRssnr+'\n'+latlng.toString();
                    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title("Signal Info").snippet(snippet).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(color)));
                    CameraPosition position = CameraPosition.builder().target(latlng).zoom(16).bearing(0).build();
                    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position));
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
            };
```

The values that I want to refresh it is into `String snippet` value. These values I take them from another class using the function below.

```
public void test(int LteSignalStrength,int LteRsrp,int LteRsrq,int LteRssnr,int LteCqi){
        MapRsrp=LteRsrp;
        MapRsrq=LteRsrq;
        MapRssnr=LteRssnr;
        MapCqi=LteCqi;
    }
```

Anyone know how can I do this?Thank you.

Comment: Your question, as stated, is not clear at all.
You have a bunch of markers with some labels and you want these labels changed every time a location change event occurs?

Comment: @copolii.Yes ,marker's labels include the values from test() which change during the time.The problem is that every marker keep the data into values from the first marker.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification above you have some markers on the map, each with a label. The label's content is determined by calling the `test` method from another class. Every time the user's location changes, you want to update these markers' labels with new values from `test`. I hope I got that right.

You need references to your markers, which you get when you first add the marker to the map. You'd store these either in a list or a map, depending on how you need to access them. For example, if all you need to do is to update all the labels, a list would suffice. If you need to also be able to get a specific marker, you'd want to put them in a map keyed by some unique id that would make that exact marker easily accessible to you.

Once you have that, within the `onLocationChanged` callback, you'd loop through all your markers, call `test` to obtain the new values, and update the labels.

For a more efficient use of the device's battery, you'd want to switch to the [Fused Location APIs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates).